# xamarin non-english dot and comma calculations (Xamarin multi-language support)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

We are developing a mobile application using Xamarin cross platform development for Android and iOS, which is reading data from a Bluetooth device that transfers data as a float i.e. 12.22 and it will support multiple languages.

When it's set to English all our calculations are fine, but when set to non-english the calculations go completely wrong. I know what is wrong in non-english languages it's treating the "." as an "," which is means a 12.22 becomes 12,22. Therefore, screwing up our calculations.

I have found similar problems, but they force the complete language to English which means we lose the translations and other fixes look very complex for what must be a simple fix.

Is there a easy fix to this problem, like setting a flag in the Xamarin multi-language support

Update : 
With the BLE transfer code, we can see the string but when it convert it we get 6000000 for French or 60 for English.

```
 private async Task<double> 
 GetDatastoreValue(Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IService service, string param)
    {
        try
        {
            var datastore_param_char = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(datastore_param_uid));
            var datastore_param_val = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(datastore_value_uid));

            await datastore_param_char.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param));
            byte[] result = await datastore_param_val.ReadAsync();

            string rslt = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
            Debug.WriteLine("GetDatastoreValue -> result " + result);
            double val = Convert.ToDouble(rslt);
            Debug.WriteLine("GetDatastoreValue -> val -> "+ val);
            return val;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can specify a format when you parse the data - presumably it comes across as a string - but since you didn't provide any code I can't give you a specific example.  Please post the code for your data parsing if you want me to elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using this

```
double val = Convert.ToDouble(rslt);
```

do this

```
double val = Double.Parse(rslt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

this will force it to evaluate "123.45" using the decimal separator, regardless of what the user's local culture might be set to

Comment: That is truly amazing, how do. you know this stuff? I would have never have found that solution. Many thanks